# UWP - How to prevent the window from being resized?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have set a certain size and minimum for the window, but how can I make the window size constant, i.e. static?

```
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(1080, 500);
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(1500, 500));
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

Comment: You cannot force a specific size. UWP apps run on phones and Xbox, where all apps run fullscreen.

Comment: Why is this function not implemented?

Comment: I just explained. Some UWP systems support only fullscreen apps. Even the desktop platform has tablet mode.